# React native TextInput limit decimal points to 8 with regex causes flickery

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, textinput

I want to limit user to enter maximum of 8 digits after decimal point. I was able to do it with regex. However, The user sees 9th character shortly before removal. It causes flickery.

https://snack.expo.dev/N5IcDRFWc

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';

const TextInputExample = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState('');

  const handlePriceChange = (value: any) => {
    const regex = /^-?\d*([.,]\d{0,8})?$/;
    if (value === "" || regex.test(value)) {
      setPrice(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView >

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={handlePriceChange}
        value={price}
        placeholder="useless placeholder"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    marginTop: 66,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default TextInputExample;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it with dynamic maxLength with regard to user's cursor.

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';

const TextInputExample = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState('');
const [maxLength, setMaxLength] = React.useState(100);

  const handlePriceChange = (value: any) => {
    const regex = /^-?\d*([.,]\d{0,8})?$/;
    if (value === "" || regex.test(value)) {
      setPrice(value);
    }
  };

  const determineMaxLength = (cursor: number) => {
    console.log("price: ", price)
    const parts = price
      .replace(",", ".")
      .split('.');

    if (parts.length === 2) {
      // If there's a decimal point and some decimal values, calculate the max length
      const p1Length = parts[0].length;

      if (cursor <= p1Length) {
        return 100;
      } else {
        // 1 for dot, 8 for decimals
        return p1Length + 1 + 8;
      }
    }

    return 100;
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView >

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={handlePriceChange}
        value={price}
        maxLength={maxLength}
        onSelectionChange={(e: any) => {
          const cursor = e.nativeEvent.selection.start;
  
          setMaxLength(determineMaxLength(cursor))
        }}
        placeholder="useless placeholder"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    marginTop: 66,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default TextInputExample;
```